# Why my Asp.Net Core proyect crushes? How can I fix it in the next time?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, console, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I'm making a web page with Asp.Net Core. I love it! I'm trying to create database migrations.
So, when I use this command:

```
dotnet ef info -s OdeToFood.csproj
```

the program starts to create thousands of files with the name "...".

After that, I will can't load the project again because this one is frozen. So, I delete it.

Do you know why this happens? Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi blurfus, I don't know really. I can tell you the steps I did before executing the command.

Comment: 1) I created this connection string:                                                   "ConnectionsStrings": {
    "OdeToFoodDb": "Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectsV13; Initial catalog = OdeToFoodCatalog; Integrated Security = True;"
  }

Comment: 2) I create a class to can work with the dbcontext:                                                                               using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OdeToFood.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace OdeToFood.Data
{
    public class OdeToFoodDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Restaurant> db { get; set; }

        public OdeToFoodDbContext(DbContextOptions<OdeToFoodDbContext> options)
            :base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}

Comment: 3) Then, I add the conecction to the app:                                                                 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddDbContextPool<OdeToFoodDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer("OdeToFoodDb");
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IRestaurantData, InRestaurantData>();
        }